# Sine function definition formula

Tags: functions, trigonometry, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I just learned about the definition of the sine function.

$$ \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

I wanted to make an accurate implementation of this function.

When I plugged $e^{ix}$ when $x = 5$ on my calculator, I got $0.283662185463-0.958924274663i$

Can someone tell me how the calculator solved this and maybe give me a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculator solved this by using:
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
Or for the engineers:
$$e^{j\theta}=\cos\theta+j\sin\theta$$

Comment: What happens to the euler identity equation with i is negative?

Comment: @IrrationalPerson "$i$" is not negative, it is the complex unit. $\theta$ could be negative though.

Comment: @graydad okay, "i" is not negative, but I found out that the plus sign is reversed in the euler identity. Thanks

Comment: @IrrationalPerson $$\cos -\theta = \cos \theta, \sin -\theta = -\sin \theta$$

Comment: @IrrationalPerson that is because sine is an odd function so $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Once you define sine function by exp function, I think you should not go back to sine function again, and calculation should(if not will) be done by Tayler expansion which defines exp function.

Comment: I do not think calculating sin functions with taylor series is an efficent method nor accurate method considering I have already implemented a version and it loses precision very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your rational comment. I noticed I once calculated by Tayler expansion and this showed very slow convergence.

Comment: User shahar mistakenly thought my definition of sin was actually the definition of sinh, but we cleared that up.